# PHP address array tree node using string or array

Tags: php, arrays, tree

Say, I have data in a tree structure implemented as an array of arrays to an arbitrary depth, something like

```
print_r($my_array);

Array
(
    [id] => 123
    [value] => Hello, World!
    [child] => Array
        (
            [name] => Foo
            [bar] => baz
        )

    [otherchild] => Array
        (
            [status] => fubar
            [list] => Array
                (
                    [one] => 1
                    [two] => 3
                )

        )

    [sanity] => unchecked
)
```

Now, using a single string as key I would like to address a node at an arbitrary depth, Let's say I have a key something like this:

```
$key = 'otherchild|list|two';
```

Using this key I want to be able to address the value stored in

```
$my_array['otherchild']['list']['two']
```

Obviously I can explode('|', $key) to get an array of keys, and shifting values off of this and using those to address sub-arrays makes it easy to obtain the value I'm looking for, something like

```
$value = $my_array;
$keys = explode('|', $key);
while ($k = array_shift($keys)) {
    if (isset($value[$k])) {
        $value = $value[$k];
    } else {
        // handle failure
    }
} // Here, if all keys exist, $value holds value of addressed node
```

But I'm stuck trying to update values in a generic way, ie without having to resort to something like

```
$keys = explode('|', $key);
if (count($keys) == 1) {
    $my_array[$keys[0]] = $new_value;
} else if (count($keys) == 2) {
    $my_array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]] = $new_value;
} else if ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use references and an approach similar with the one you use on read. When you cannot find a node, just create it and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setAt(array & $a, $key, $value)
{
    $keys = explode('|', $key);
    // Start with the root node (the array itself)
    $node = & $a;
    // Walk the tree, create nodes as needed
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        // Create node if it does not exist
        if (! isset($node[$k])) {
             $node[$k] = array();
        }
        // Walk to the node
        $node = & $node[$k];
    }

    // Position found; store the value
    $node = $value;
}


// Test
$array = array();

// Add new values
setAt($array, 'some|key', 'value1');
setAt($array, 'some|otherkey', 'val2');
setAt($array, 'key3', 'value3');
print_r($array);
// Overwrite existing values
setAt($array, 'some|key', 'new-value');
print_r($array);

setAt($array, 'some', 'thing');
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a short answer, you can also use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

```
$elem = "\$array['" . str_replace("|", "']['", $key) . "']";
$val = eval("return isset($elem) ? $elem : null;");
```

Comment: **DON'T** do this. It's slow, ugly and, if the value of `$key` comes from user input, it's also dangerous.

Comment: Noticeably slow? Meh, if you care. Ugly? Code is not always meant to be pretty. Dangerous? PDO::query is just as dangerous as it can lead to SQL injection if it's misused. As a developer, you should know to use functions carefully.

Comment: I agree but I still prefer to not use `eval()` :-)